# How to have a flex-item that expands to fit a centered flex box, up to a certain max-width?

Tags: css, flexbox

**In the demo below, I want the green box to tighten to fit exactly around the red and blue boxes.**

The green box is a flexbox that I want to use as the center column for a page. This flexbox contains two items.

The first is the blue box which has a fixed width.

The second is the red box. I want this item to use the remaining space in the flexbox, but up to a certain `max-width`.

However, I want the flexbox container to limit its width to the size of the flex items. In other words, I want the red box to grow up to a certain point if it has room, then let the red and blue boxes determine the width of the green box.

Things I've tried that don't quite work for my use case:

- **Set a `max-width` on `#column`**: The element `#left` won't always exist, so this `max-width` will be too large in those cases.
- **Set `width: fit-content` on `#column`**: This limits the size of the flexbox. So if `#right` doesn't contain much ontent (as in this example), `#right` won't expand up to its `max-width`.
- **Using CSS Grid:** This has a few other tradeoffs for the layout I'm working on and isn't a great option.

Before I explore other alternatives, is there a pure CSS solution to get what I'm hoping for?

```css
body {
  background: #ccc;
  margin: 0;
}

#column {
  background: #fff;
  min-height: 50vh;
  margin: 20vh auto;
  justify-content: center;
  display: flex;
  border: 3px #8F8 solid;
}

#left {
  border: 3px #F88 solid;
  width: 120px; /* A fixed value */
}

#right {
  border: 3px #88F solid;
  max-width: 200px; 
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id='column'>
    <div id='left'>
    Left flex item:<br>Fixed width of 120px
    </div>
    <div id='right'>
    Right flex item:<br>Expand up to 200px
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution that works for my use case: instead of trying to coax `#right` to expand to fill the empty space, force `#right` to reach its full width first, then let it shrink if necessary.

1. Set `body` to `display: flex`
2. For `#right`, set `width: 200px` and `flex-shrink: 1` (`flex-basis` didn't work)

Note that this works even if you remove the `#left` element entirely.

Final working CSS:

```css
body {
  background: #ccc;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
}

#column {
  background: #fff;
  min-height: 50vh;
  margin: 20vh auto;
  justify-content: center;
  display: flex;
  border: 3px #8F8 solid;
}

#left {
  border: 3px #F88 solid;
  width: 120px; /* A fixed value */
}

#right {
  border: 3px #88F solid;
  width: 200px;
  flex-shrink: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id='column'>
    <div id='left'>
    Left flex item:<br>Fixed width of 120px
    </div>
    <div id='right'>
    Right flex item:<br>Expand up to 200px
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Edit: Updated solution.

I am adding an extra markup (#container) as the flex-box container.

```css
body {
  background: #ccc;
  margin: 0;
}

#column {
  background: #fff;
  border: 3px #8F8 solid;
  
  margin-top: 20vh;
  margin-left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%); /* To centralize the whole element*/
    
  display:inline-block; /*Makes the #column wrap around the content*/
  
}

#container{
  display:flex;
  min-height: 50vh; /*Controls the height*/
}
#left {
  border: 3px #F88 solid;
  width: 120px; /* A fixed value */
}

#right {
  border: 3px #88F solid;
  max-width: 200px; 
}
```

```html
<div id='column'>
  <div id="container">
    <div id='left'>
    Left flex item:<br>Fixed width of 120px
    </div>
    <div id='right'>
    Right flex item:<br>Expand up to 200px hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh
      hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh
    </div>
  </div>
    
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately this doesn't quite work because there are cases where `#left` won't exist: then what happens is there ends up with extra space in the flexbox.

Comment: I have updated my solution. Sorry I missed the part in your requirement that said "The element #left won't always exist".

Answer (score 0):

Flex can be imbricated. here the parents container are html and body but could be any other tags.

```css
html {
  display: flex;
}

body {
  background: #ccc;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#column {
  background: #fff;
  min-height: 50vh;
  margin: 20vh auto;
  justify-content: center;
  display: flex;
  border: 3px #8F8 solid;
}

#left {
  border: 3px #F88 solid;
  width: 120px;
  /* A fixed value */
}

#right {
  border: 3px #88F solid;
  max-width: 200px;
  /* flex-grow: 1; */ /* what do you expect from that rule ? */
}
```

```html
<div id='column'>
  <div id='left'>
    Left flex item: Fixed width of 120px
  </div>
  <div id='right'>
    Right flex item: Expand up to 200px
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! However this doesn't quite work if the contents of `#right` won't reach the `max-width` on their own. E.g., if you add a line break in `#right`, then that box won't fill 200px. I updated my code snippet to add the line breaks.

Comment: @Paul add  `min-width: 320px;` to column element?

Comment: @Paul i only minded the part **I want the green box to tighten to fit exactly around the red and blue boxes** , for the sizing of the inside boxes it is  up to you. max or min width or height or from the content, you may also use the grid model to access other options/ways to set the columns's width. its , to me, another classic question ;) . But maybe it is flex-grow:1 that  you do not need here ? so it shrinks on its content untill max-width is reached